# Overloading a android application?

Tags: java, android, methods

My program is being designed as a sliding puzzle game. I'm currently working on the shuffle button that will use random numbers to move tiles a certain amount of time so that the board can be solved by the player.

Currently I'm stuck with a error message : 'Could not execute method of the activity' caused when I press the shuffle button. When it was outside of the while loop i could keep pressing the button, but I had to leave a certain amount of time between each click. Im thinking im overloading the program some how... but im not sure how to reduce the load...

```
    public void shuffleTiles(View v){ //Shuffles the tiles using random numbers

    int tileToMove;

    while (computerMoves < 5){
        tileToMove = randomNumbers.nextInt(12);
        moveTile(tileToMove, false);
    }
```

The main crux of the program is worked around this method, which swaps images to show that the tiles have moved:

```
    private void moveTile(int button, boolean playerMove) { //The main method which causes a tile to be moved

    int tileToReplace = movePossibleTest(button); //Run the test to see if there is a blank square next to it
    if (tileToReplace != 0){

        Drawable originalImage = buttons[button-1].getDrawable(); //Saves a drawable of the original image
        Drawable blankImage = buttons[tileToReplace-1].getDrawable(); //Saves a drawable of the blank tile

        buttons[button-1].setImageDrawable(blankImage); //Swaps the images
        buttons[button-1].setTag("blank");

        buttons[tileToReplace-1].setImageDrawable(originalImage); //Swaps the tags that identify which is the blank tag
        buttons[tileToReplace-1].setTag(null);

        if (playerMove){ //If the move was initiated by a player click
            moveCount(true);
        }
        else moveCount(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should use a while loop with the ui thread - its really memory intensive. In fact, I don't see why you're using the while loop in the first place.

Comment: I'm using it to shuffle to tiles, but now I think about it, I might run it without changing any ui's in the process virtually, then swap all the tiles into their calculated positions, would that overload it?

Comment: What is manipulating computerMoves ?

Comment: computerMoves is a count record for all the moves automatically generated (without human interaction) for use when I implement the solve button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have other activities that are bogging down your app you can make sure that you close them by using the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) . This helped me solve some freezes in one particular project.